# Why is GnuPG asking for my passcode only when signing?

Tags: gnupg, macos

On my Mac, I had originally installed GnuPG using homebrew.

Then I found GPGTools and started to use that because it is more user-friendly (OS hotkeys, so I can easily use encryption inside an email for example).

I did not do any setting up of keys using the `gpg` I obtained through homebrew. I set up my identity with GPGTools.

Eventually (after a while), I discovered that even without choosing the "save in keychain" checkbox, out of all four operations (encryption, signing, decryption, verification), only the signing step requires my passcode.

I know that the way it works is that I need to use my private key for the sign and decrypt operations. So it was bothering me that I was in a state where signing always requires the passcode and decrypting never did (after the first time I entered it).

Once I have gone and updated `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` to add `no-use-agent` and killed `gpg-agent` now it properly makes me enter the passcode for signing and decrypting.

My question is, what about the functionality of `gpg-agent` which (when it was still running) made it save my passcode but *only* for decrypting and not for signing?

Comment: signing is a rather active action (you only sign every now and then, except for when you make signed backups) wheras decryption happens at a much higher frequency usually, meaning users would get annoyed extremely quickly by the constant requests for passphrases (for example when you're searching through your encrypted emails)

Comment: @SEJPM OK that makes sense, it's still not clear to me that this is the intended default behavior though.

Answer (score 3):

Not all of the four operations you mentioned require the passphrase to be entered, but only those making use of the private key: decryption and signing. Both encryption and verification as counter-parts of decryption and signing only make use of the public key, which is not stored in an encrypted (passphrase-protected) manner.

Some people prefer the passphrase to be cached for decryption of encrypted messages, but be queries for the passphrase all the time if signing messages. Either, because they consider faked but correctly signed messages more dangerous than messages decrypted by an attacker, or because they want to prevent accidental signing of messages.

`gpg-agent` knows several options to fine-tune its caching behavior, among those `--default-cache-ttl` to define *how long* passphrases are cached, and `--ignore-cache-for-signing`, which prevents GnuPG to request the passphrase anyway for signing.

From `man gpg-agent`:

> **`--ignore-cache-for-signing`**
>
> This option will let gpg-agent bypass the passphrase cache for all signing operation.  Note that there is also a per-session option to control this behaviour but this com‐mand line option takes precedence.
>
> **`--default-cache-ttl n`**
>
> Set the time a cache entry is valid to n seconds.  The default is 600 seconds.  Each time a cache entry is accessed, the entry's timer is reset.  To set an entry's maximum lifetime, use `max-cache-ttl`.

Very likely, you set `ignore-cache-for-signing` in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, which is not default.

Comment: `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` is an empty file owned by root and thus read-only. It was likely overwritten by the GPGTools installer program or something. I wonder if it is just better for me to remove the command line gpg and only use GPGTools because of these config file conflicts.

Comment: GPGTools is not an implementation of OpenPGP on its own, but a distribution of GnuPG and other software. It brings the GnuPG binary, along with several other addons for other applications like Apple Mail and graphical user interfaces, which all in the end rely on GnuPG. Actually, most of them will require `gpg-agent` indirectly. Everything in `~/.gnupg` should be owned by your system user, not root, which you can fix by taking ownership through `sudo chown -R $USER ~/.gnupg` (OS X' "Fix permissions" does similar things for the operating system files).

Comment: Yes I am merely pointing out that it must have been my installation process that resulted in the files not being in the state we expect, because homebrew does not run with root privileges and I never ran `gpg` as root, therefore any file owned by root must have been dumped in by GPGTools. Indeed I think GPGTools provides `gpg-agent` and other executables inside of its application bundle which it runs, at least it seems that way from `htop`